# How to get available quantity of product?

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart

I am adding products in cart programmatically. But whenever I enter quantity more than available, it gives me a 503 error. e.g. Lets say a product has 7 quantity saved in admin and out of 7, 3 is already added into cart. So now 4 quantity is available.
But if I try to add more than 4 it gives me 503 error.

Now I want to add a check for quantity before adding into the cart. Is it possible?

I am using below code to add product into cart.

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(1);
        $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
        $cart->init();
        $cart->addProduct($_product, array('qty' => 5);
        $cart->save();
        Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are approaching your problem from the wrong angle.

I guess you are seeing a `500` error because of an uncaught exception. The quote and cart models throw exceptions if the product cannot be added to the cart.

Use `try ... catch` to catch this exception and react accordingly.

#### Example:

```
try {
    $cart->addProduct($_product, array('qty' => 5);
    $cart->save()
} catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addException($e, $this->__('Cannot add the item to shopping cart.'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(4767);

$stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty();
```

now check your qty value with that of the stock before adding to cart.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a product cart then request qty will be available for cart not only available for  qty also depends on there are few field like:

- `max_sale_qty`
- `min_qty`
- `backorder`

etc

above fields value are set  basic of system configuration value or product wise setting .

**So When you will cart then you need check those condition**